# How to 'transform' a String object (containing XML) to an element on an existing JSP page

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Currently, I have a String object that contains XML elements:

```
String carsInGarage = garage.getCars();
```

I now want to pass this String as an input/stream source (or some kind of source), but am unsure which one to choose and how to implement it.

Most of the solutions I have looked at import the package: javax.xml.transform and accept a XML file (stylerXML.xml) and output to a HTML file (outputFile.html) (See code below).

```
try 
{
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("styler.xsl"));

    transformer.transform(new StreamSource("stylerXML.xml"), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("outputFile.html")));
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to accept a String object and output (using XSL) to a  element within an existing JSP page. I just don't know how to implement this, even having looked at the code above.

Can someone please advise/assist. I have searched high and low for a solution, but I just can't pull anything out.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use a [`StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) and a [`StringWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html):

```
try {
    StringReader reader = new StringReader("<xml>blabla</xml>");
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(
            new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource("styler.xsl"));

    transformer.transform(
            new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(reader), 
            new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));

    String result = writer.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi Bruno,
Thank you for that excellent answer.
It is compiling properly now :)

However, I still am unable to print it to the screen.

I am currently trying:
out.println(writer);

but this is failing.

Comment: Maybe there was an error with the transform ... how exactly is it failing?

Comment: It fails as nothing is printed to the browser.

At the bottom of my try block I have:
String result = writer.toString();
out.print("<div>" + result + "</div>");

I also just installed a tool called Firebug to inspect the content of my HTML body.

Nothing again.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I can out.print() a random string outside of the TRY-block. But I cannot out.print() the same random string when it is inside the TRY-block.

Comment: Hi Bruno, I have managed to get the transformed/styled XML output to screen. I must thank you for your assistance. You are amazing :)
I do have one question left though :P
Did you expect the original string AS WELL as the transformed/styled XML to output together? Or did you just expect the transformed/styled only to show?

Comment: No. Only the transformed/styled result is in the writer. If your getting strange results check your XSL.

Answer (score 0):

If at some point you want the source to contain more than just a single string, or you don't want to generate the XML wrapper element manually, create a DOM document that contains your source and pass it to the transformer using a [DOMSource](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/dom/DOMSource.html).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
String str = "<my>xml</my>"    
StreamSource src = new StreamSource(new StringReader(str));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Result res = new StreamResult(baos);
transformer.transform(src, res);
```