# How to apply xsl to xml in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

This is problaby been asked a bunch of times, but I didn't really find what I was looking for exactly.
I don't normally code in Java, but in C# so I am not comfortable with Java classes and such.

**Question**

I need to create a method that takes 2 paramaters.
1. A string parameter (the xml - so needs to be converted to some xml class) 
2. A string parameter with the xsl file path location

The thing is I am making a factory class that must convert xml from a webservice into xml that my system can understand. I need a nice solution for that.
Every method on the ws will have a xsl file - both the request (convert my xml to something that the ws understands) and the response (convert to something that my system understands).

Comment: The title says `XSL`, the question itself and the tag say `XLS`. I guess you mean `XSL` (`XLS` is MS Excel file format).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT processing with Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604497/xslt-processing-with-java)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might find the Java Almanac a useful resource.

notably [The Quintessential Program That Transforms an XML File with XSL](http://www.exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.xml.transform/BasicXsl.html).  Example copied from the page (as it keeps disappearing)

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class BasicXsl {
    // This method applies the xslFilename to inFilename and writes
    // the output to outFilename.
    public static void xsl(String inFilename, String outFilename, String xslFilename) {
        try {
            // Create transformer factory
            TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

            // Use the factory to create a template containing the xsl file
            Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(
                new FileInputStream(xslFilename)));

            // Use the template to create a transformer
            Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();

            // Prepare the input and output files
            Source source = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(inFilename));
            Result result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));

            // Apply the xsl file to the source file and write the result
            // to the output file
            xformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            // An error occurred in the XSL file
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            // An error occurred while applying the XSL file
            // Get location of error in input file
            SourceLocator locator = e.getLocator();
            int col = locator.getColumnNumber();
            int line = locator.getLineNumber();
            String publicId = locator.getPublicId();
            String systemId = locator.getSystemId();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map>
    <entry key="key1" value="value1" />
    <entry key="key2" />
</map>
```

Sample XSLT program:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="map">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Map</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>=<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    <br></br>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting HTML from running the example is:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Map</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    key1=value1<br>
    key2=<br>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I think the sample is okay, but it outputs the file to disk. I probably need it in a memorystream and then finally return it as a string (probably by going through the stream bit for bit?)

Comment: Have a look at the StreamResult class.

Comment: Appears to be domain squatted.  I do not know where they went.

Comment: Link is alive here: http://www.exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.xml.transform/BasicXsl.html

Comment: Example for usage `StreamResult` in combination with a Transformer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/852010/2049986

Comment: You can use ByteArrayOutputStream to create StreamResult to avoid writing to disk: like this :  new StreamResult(new ByteArrayOutputStream())

Answer (score 1):

Google for "JAXP tutorial" - there are lots of resources available.

Though if you want to use XSLT 2.0 (and believe me, you do!), you'll be using Saxon, and Saxon offers both JAXP and its own API (called s9api) which helps you take advantage of all the new features in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Even though I recognize your authority on the subject, the "believe me, you do" argument might be replaced with a brief self-standing explanation on why it is so much better.  Personally we can make do with XSLT 1.0 in 99% of the cases, which is present in the standard Java runtime.  Also you may want to mention that the really interesting versions of Saxon has a price.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0407.html, hope that answers your question